# Footer overlapping content with media queries

Tags: html, css

I have this simple footer that I wish to always be at the bottom of the page.

Currently it is fixed to the bottom of the page but when the contents of the page is taller and requires scrolling the footer lays on top of the code, not at the bottom.

```css
  .footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8vh;
  background-color: #000000;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 16vh;
    background-color: #000000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

A pointer would really be appreciated & having no white space at the bottom. I've tried sticky but that hasn't worked either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help a lot to have some screenshot, or a visual cue of what your'e after.
A "current state", and "desired state" would be ideal.

Comment: @Adriano please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4bufgm0/) I'm at the point where it sticks, I've got it within another DIV for the entire body. Only issue now is the small amount of white space below the footer.

Comment: That's because the `body` has a margin of 8px. Try to remove that or override it and you'll be alright.

Comment: I can't see where you mean @Adriano

Comment: Look in the css panel here: https://jsfiddle.net/v61m5czd/

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the footer to remain fixed (always visible) to the bottom of the page, you could give the `<body>` a padding that is equal to the height of the footer. That way no content will remain hidden behind the footer.

Comment: That hasn't worked. I don't want the footer always visible at the bottom. I want it at the bottom of the document. If there's not enough space to fill screen that's the only time the footer should be pushed to the bottom.

Comment: still nothing. Would appreciate an example.

Comment: If you are using floats, try [this](https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx). If you are using flex, try [this](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/).

Comment: Neither of those are helpful @Dave, as they don't match with what I've coded. I already have the desired effect. I just don't want the overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I learned a way from [Here](https://matthewjamestaylor.com/bottom-footer) That might help you. Just need to structure your HTML as below:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

And declare your styles like this:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

It works for me and hope helps you as well.

Comment: I've tried this too. This method ends up with the rest of the page scrolling and the footer staying where the bottom originally was.

Comment: When it does catch up you still end up with the footer on top of the rest of the content.

Comment: I think I didn't get you mean exactly, but I made a fiddle for you to test it. In my code the footer gets down with the content and if there were not content it remains at the bottom of the page. If it does not fix your issue, please provide more details of want you want or a full code.
https://jsfiddle.net/Irandoust/mvw617nt/1/

Comment: Getting closer. I've used `vh` because this scales better. See [this fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/k4bufgm0/), I just need there to be no white space below it.

Comment: Below the footer? Using `display: table;` for the footer will fix this issue. It scales the footer to all of its content.

Comment: Amazing, @Irandoust. The space is still there but it matches my background colour. Thank You :)

Comment: Your welcome, glad it helps. And the remaining space at the bottom of the fiddle is the body padding. If you have it on your original code, you can remove it via `body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}`. Happy coding :)

Comment: I'd already removed it, thanks. Just have an issue now with there being horizontal overflow?

Comment: Please describe more about the overflow. It depends on the others styles.

Comment: Fixed it. There was padding affecting the width of a DIV because it was 100% plus padding. Thank you though :)